# Hover LI to show div

Tags: jquery, css, hover, jquery-hover

I asked similiar question on here, and eventough i got some answers, i didnt managed to make it work.
In short, i have a UL list like this:

```
<ul class="productlist">
      <li><a href="#" id="link0" class="product-link">Caviar</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" id="link1" class="product-link">Athena</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" id="link2" class="product-link">Knot</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" id="link3" class="product-link">Brooke Leaf</a></li>
</ul>
```

Bellow that, i have 4 DIV's.
All of them except the first one should be hidden, and only opened when the user hovers over their LI link above.
So, in short.User comes to the page, first link is opened.He hovers over second, and second one appears, same thing with third, fourth...

```
<div id="boxlink0">Some text for the first link</div>
<div id="boxlink1">Some text for the second link</div>
<div id="boxlink2">Some text for the third link</div>
<div id="boxlink3">Some text for the fourth link</div>
```

Comment: if this is a navigation menu, usually the divs go inside the li and positioned absolutely. If you do that, this can be done via css instead of resorting to jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this simple script:

```
var $boxes = $('.boxlink');
$('.productlist .product-link').mouseover(function() {
    $boxes.hide().filter('#box' + this.id).show();
});
```

I added helper class `boxlink` to all divs for convenience. You also need a little CSS to show the first div by default:

```css
.boxlink {
    display: none;
}
#boxlink0 {
    display: block;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Vg4SH/

Comment: Hey! Honestly, thanks a bunch for your help.Just tried it following your instructions, but for some reason it wont work...
Would it be rude if i sent you a link so you can take a look?

http://tinyurl.com/onhovershow Only the first div is showed, but altough i included JS into header, it isnt showing others on hover...

Comment: You can send me a link, sure.

Comment: Thank you, and again, sorry for being boring :)

Comment: You didn't send me anything, how do I know?

Comment: My bad, i did place the link in my previous message, but maybe you didnt saw it.
tinyurl.com/onhovershow

Comment: Ups, it's my bad. My code from the post had an error. Take updated version it should work.

Comment: I know im damn boring, but it isnt...I dont know am i doing something wrong, is this how is should include it in header? http://jsfiddle.net/RRjh3/

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `hover` to affect elements which aren't descendants or siblings of the hovered element.

But you could change your html to

```
<dl class="productlist">
    <dt><a href="#" id="link0" class="product-link">Caviar</a></dt>
    <dd id="boxlink0">Some text for the first link</dd>
    <dt><a href="#" id="link1" class="product-link">Athena</a></dt>
    <dd id="boxlink1">Some text for the second link</dd>
    <dt><a href="#" id="link2" class="product-link">Knot</a></dt>
    <dd id="boxlink2">Some text for the third link</dd>
    <dt><a href="#" id="link3" class="product-link">Brooke Leaf</a></dt>
    <dd id="boxlink3">Some text for the fourth link</dd>
</dl>
```

and use

```
.productlist dd {
    display: none;
}
.productlist > dt:hover + dd {
    display: block;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/p8NFt/2/)

And if you want descriptions to appear below all definitions, you could use `position: absolute` to place them at the bottom: [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/p8NFt/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".productlist li a").hover(function(e){
    e.stopPropogation(); // to stop bubbling
    $("#box" +$(this).attr(id)).show();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should get the job done.  Usually I reply to see what you have attempted first, but this was easy enough.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".productList li").hover(function(){
        $("#box"+$(this).attr("id")).show();
    },function(){
        $("#box"+$(this).attr("id")).hide();
    });
    $("#boxlink0").show();
    $("#boxlink1, #boxlink2, #boxlink3").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap all divs into a wrapper div and initally apply css for making only first div visible

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="boxlink0">Some text for the first link</div>
  <div id="boxlink1">Some text for the second link</div>
  <div id="boxlink2">Some text for the third link</div>
  <div id="boxlink3">Some text for the fourth link</div>
<div>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper div
{
    display:none;
}
#wrapper div:first-child
{
    display:block;
}
```

Then check which li has been hovered on using index() property and then show the corresponding div using jquery

```
$('ul li a').hover(function(e){
    var liNumber=$(this).parent('li').index();
    $('#wrapper div').css('display','none');
    $('#wrapper div:nth-child('+(liNumber+1)+')').show();
})
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/huF8Z/

Answer (score 0):

See working [Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/gqa6W/)

First apply css display none to last 3 divs:

```
#boxlink1, #boxlink2, #boxlink3 {
    display:none
}
```

then write this js code:

```
$('#link0').hover(function(){
    $('#boxlink0').css('display','block');
    $('#boxlink1, #boxlink2, #boxlink3').css('display','none');
});

$('#link1').hover(function(){
    $('#boxlink1').css('display','block');
    $('#boxlink0, #boxlink2, #boxlink3').css('display','none');
});

$('#link2').hover(function(){
    $('#boxlink2').css('display','block');
    $('#boxlink0, #boxlink1, #boxlink3').css('display','none');
});

$('#link3').hover(function(){
    $('#boxlink3').css('display','block');
    $('#boxlink0, #boxlink1, #boxlink2').css('display','none');
});
```