# jquery show/hide ul with same class

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I have below html structure. When somebody mouseover on main_cat ul, li (maincat_1), i want to show corresponding ul with subcat_1

```
<div style="display:none;" id="dd_top_cat">
    <div class="main_cat">
    <ul>
        <li class="maincat_1"><span>Vehicles</span></li>
        <li class="maincat_8"><span>Properties</span></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="sub_cat">
        <ul style="display:none;" class="ul_subcat_1" id="subcat_1">
            <li>Boats</li>
            <li>Cars</li>
            <li>Motorcycles</li>
            <li>Light Commercials</li>
            <li>Accessories &amp; Parts</li>
            <li>Other Vehicles</li>
        </ul>
        <ul style="display:none;" class="ul_subcat_8" id="subcat_8">
            <li>Apartments</li>
            <li>Houses</li>
            <li>Commercial Properties</li>
            <li>Land</li>
            <li>Rooms</li>
            <li>Other Properties</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and make it better?

Comment: a jsfiddle wil be great help

Comment: which class you have hide?

Comment: where is JS code which you tried

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {     

    $('.main_cat').find('li').mouseover(function () {          
        szClass = $(this).attr('class');
        szClass = szClass.replace("main", "ul_sub");
        $('.sub_cat').find("ul").css("display", "none");
        $('.sub_cat').find("ul." + szClass).css("display", "");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the un-formatted question. I was looking for below answer,
[Hover LI to show div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22232793/hover-li-to-show-div)